# Show concatenated text for collections_select option text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collections_select:

`collection_select(:building, :room_id, Room.all, :id, :name, prompt: true)`:

```
<select name="building[room_id]">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Room A</option>
  <option value="2">Room B</option>
  <option value="3">Room C</option>
</select>
```

I would like to have `:name` and `:number` as the text for the options tag:

```
<select name="building[room_id]">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Room A - 101</option>
  <option value="2">Room B - 102</option>
  <option value="3">Room C -103</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `room.rb` model, add a method to concatenate two fields.

```
def name_with_number
  name << " - " << number
end
```

Then update your `collection_select` as:

```
collection_select(:building, :room_id, Room.all, :id, :name_with_number, prompt: true)
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

so create method and use it instead name

```
collection_select(:building, :room_id, Room.all, :id, :name_with_number, prompt: true)
```

where name_with_number is your method like

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name_with_number
     "#{name} #{id}" #or whatever
   end
end
```

More details http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select